# How can I use a string in image `alt` tag without encode by AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, encode

If I have this `AngularJs` code:

```
<div class="myStyle">
    TITLE:
    {{product.title}}
</div>
```

I want show `title` without encode. so I know it's one solution:

```
<div class="myStyle">
    TITLE:
    <span ng-bind-html="product.title"></span>
</div>
```

But I don't happy about extra `<span>` code!

Also if I have this code:

```
<img src="img.jpg" alt="{{product.title}}">
```

I can not use extra `span`, Now how can I show `title` in `alt` tag of image without encode?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that since you use `ng-bind-html` that `product.title` is html string , not text

You could create a custom filter that returns text from html string

```
app.filter('htmlToText', function(){
  return function(html){        
     return angular.element('<div>').append(html || '').text();
  };
});
```

View

```
<img src="img.jpg" alt="{{product.title | htmlToText}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

For showing product.title in div, if you don't like the extra span, you might try:

```
<div class="myStyle" ng-bind="product.title"></div>
```

where in your javascript code, you can add a prefix: "Title: " to product.title. (Although i don't feel having an extra span is bad)

Another side note, I see you are using ng-bind-html. Is "product.title" really html?  If it contain some styles, maybe you can revise your "myStyle" to control the style. Let data be data.

For the image one, you probably don't need to worry about the {{ }}.

I am guessing the reason you don't like {{ }} is they may show briefly before angular can render the template with the data.  However, if you put them in , the browser will not show content inside of alt unless your image is not available (If the image is really not available, you may consider revisiting your codes to make sure it is available, or to display a default image)